# Need to test the data I get from jquerys $.get

Tags: jquery, string, get

Very new to jquery so if my question is a bit out there then my apologies.

I am playing around with $.get

From.htm:

```
    <body>
    <span id="Mytest">Hello</span>
    </body>
```

index.htm:

```
    <body>
    <span id="Mytest1">BBBBBBB</span>
    <script>

    $.get('From.htm #Mytest', function(data) {
        if (data) {
           $('#Mytest1').html(data).innerHTML);
        };

    });

    </script>
    </body>
```

The above works perfectly. The inner html of #Mytest1 gets changed to Hello.

But what I would like is to have $('#Mytest1').html(data).innerHTML); as a string to test the data before I write it to #Mytest1.

I have tried several things but I am just not getting there. I think I have done ok so far. If anyone can help that would be great.

I have tried looking at "data" (alert(data)) but if I alert it-it shows the whole From.htm page. Might be doing something wrong there.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @bbarry , your resonse is a html file right??you know what response you are getting right

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all. `$('#Mytest1').html(data).innerHTML);` has an unmatched ')' at the end. alert() shows a page because that's what you're requesting. If all you want is 'hello' then your 'From.html' should have just 'hello' in it, nothing else, no `<body>` or `<span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your code as below

There is no need of innerHtml ,

```
 $.get('From.htm #Mytest', function(data) {
        if (data.length>0) { // for now if you want to check you can say .length
           $('#Mytest1').html(data);
        };

    });
```

1. If you want to just get some string from the backend , response just that string only and with some responsecode or some status
2. You can say something like data.Success and then proceed furthur
3. There are various ways you can return data , json , xml , html etc , see what suits you the most and use it.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also do this with jQuery:

```
var jqObj = $(data);
var hello = jqObj.children('#MyTest').text();
```

Basically what this does is convert the *data* object returned from the $.get request into a jquery object.  From there you can manipulate that object just like you would any other jquery object you get from using selectors.